# How to specify `application/json` Content-Type without invoking Chrome's CORS preflight request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cors, fetch

According to the fetch specs it appears that as long as a `Content-Type` is specified that is one of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "multipart/form-data", or "text/plain" and other conditions are satisfied then a POST request should not result in a preflight request. In practice however I've had a difficult time specifying multiple headers for fetch in a way that doesn't cause the OPTIONS request for the preflight check.

ex 1.

```
fetch("https://differentsubodmain.example.com/api/resource", {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain, application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({})
})
```

ex 2.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

fetch("https://differentsubodmain.example.com/api/resource", {
    headers: myHeaders,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({})
})
```

ex 3.

```
fetch("https://differentsubodmain.example.com/api/resource", {
    headers: [
        ["Content-Type", "application/json"],
        ["Content-Type", "text/plain"],
        ["Accept", "application/json"]
    ],
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({})
    })
```

Neither of these examples succeed in requesting without the preflight request but specifying either with only `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` appears to work just fine. The [example here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-cors-safelisted-request-header-content-type) however shows both being specified in a request and suggests that it shouldn't cause a preflight. Is this just an issue with different browser implementations or am I missing something?

Comment: Does it matter that your headers is an object instead of an array of arrays as in the example? Specs say it's a list, not object.

Comment: Both ways appear to work in general however neither seems to give us leeway with regard to the CORS preflight requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there no preflight in CORS for POST requests with standard content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725955/why-is-there-no-preflight-in-cors-for-post-requests-with-standard-content-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like perhaps I hadn't read that reference carefully. Below is the important excerpt.

> Warning. This intentionally does not use extract a MIME type as that algorithm is rather forgiving and servers are not expected to implement it.
>
> If extract a MIME type were used the following request would not result in a CORS preflight and a naïve parser on the server might treat the request body as JSON

It looks like we are largely constrained to the mime types `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` to avoid preflight requests for CORS.

Reference:

- https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-cors-safelisted-request-header-content-type