# CORS policy issue on Heroku Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, preflight

I made a client-server application.
The backend uses Node, Express and MongoDB Atlas.

I already installed CORS and used it as a middleware like:

```
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

Then I deployed it to heroku which returned an endpoint; like : https://express-server.herokuapp.com

I used that endpoint in my client which is based on React.

I use axios to make a request to the server such as:

```
const response = await axios.post('https://express-server.herokuapp.com/users/login' ,{some data here})
```

This is where the error occurs. Every time I make a request the following response pops up in the console.

[image]

What is the solution for this????

Comment: well, `buy-where.herokuapp.com` doesn't send CORS headers - is that your site? perhaps you need to restart your app or something on heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define in your server from which origin requests should be accepted

Assuming your localhost runs on port 3000. Try this code

```
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:3000", 
        credentials: true,
    })
);
```

NOTE: credentials true is set to pass HTTP only cookies

Answer (score 0):

Added to main.ts

```
app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to support [CORS preflight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) requests to do POST operations with json data. See this: [Why is there no preflight in CORS for POST requests with standard content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725955/why-is-there-no-preflight-in-cors-for-post-requests-with-standard-content-type)  That means handling http OPTIONS.

Something like this in your express app, before other routes.

```
app.options('*', cors())
```