# How does one build a widget on someones website and is hosted on yours?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, jsonp

*This question is a referenced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943968/give-out-widget-web-application-with-activation-code) question.*
So, after some research of `JSONP` and some testing, I've come to the conclusion, that I have no idea what I'm doing...

**What do I need?**

I am making a customer service for people to use on their website.
In the end, someone who wants our web application embedded into their website, needs to get some `JavaScript` code with a authorization key.

**What do I have?**

I have played with the code a bit and this is what I have:

```
homepage.php (client side)
```

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
var key= "12345";
var url = 'http://www.example.com/json.php?callback=?&auth=' + key + '';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       document.write(json.csBlock[0].frame); //Call to the iFrame
       // document.write(json.csBlock[0].layout);
       // document.write(json.csBlock[0].core);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

So this JavaScript requests a callback to my server...

```
json.php (server side)
```

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['auth'] === "12345"){
?>
jsonCallback(
    {
        "csBlock":
        [
            {
                "frame": "<iframe src='http://www.example.com/content/testpage.php'></iframe>",
                "layout": "<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.example.com/css/klantpage.css'>",
                "handle": "<script src='http://www.example.com/js/self/widgetScript.js'></script>",
                "core": "<div class='dashboard_widget'></div><div id='chatContainer' class='chatContainer'><div id='view_ajax' class='view_ajax'></div></div><div id='ajaxForm' class = 'ajaxForm'><textarea id='chatInput'></textarea></div><input type='button' value='Send' id='btnSend' class = 'btn btn-primary'></div></div>"

            }
        ]
    }
);
<?php
}
else {
    ?>
    jsonCallback(
    {
        "csBlock":
        [
            {
                "layout": "<div style='width: 250px; height: 50px; background-color: #842979; position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 5%; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px; text-align: center; line-height: 300%; color: white; font-family: calibri; font-size: 13pt;'>KEY NOT PERMITTED</div>"
            }
        ]
    }
);




    <?php
}
?>
```

The key that someone sends to us should be `"12345"`
So for this aspect, I think an iFrame would be bad practice... So I'm going to avoid that.
Now, as you can see in the `json.php` file I have kind of build something with the divs.
The thing is, when I build it with the divs(and also include `"handle":`), it gives me a 500 internal server error. 
And I think this is because `widgetScript.js` is trying to call a `PHP` file which is on another server...
So with the iFrame out of the way, and building it with just `HTML` elements out of the way, how many options do I have for what I know? None.

**Question**

How do I make a chat widget professionally and securely with `JSONP`?
My concern is that people could alter the `JavaScript` and use the chat widget anyway.

---

This question might be a bit too much to answer here on StackOverflow.
 So redirecting me to another website is completely fine with me.

Any tips, guides, tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: People will allways be able to alter the way they connect to your chat server, that's unavoidable. In this regard, the only method is so called security through obscurity - if your code is messy enough, attackers might just give up. Obviously this is with a risk that you get lost in the code as well.

Comment: @TomášZato Hmm... I thought about that, that seems to be a fair solution... I've seen it too... Thank you very much

Comment: @Sj03rs, and of course, do not use '12345' as key.

Comment: @JS-NL Haha, it will be randomly generated in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

*How do I make a chat widget professionally and securely with JSONP?
My concern is that people could alter the JavaScript and use the chat widget anyway.*

A better way would be to use WebSockets, it's faster and safer.

My opinions come, since I have done Professional Chat Widgets before, both for external and internal applications on the web. ( I've used both JSONP and WebSockets )

The WebSocket widget would reduce the effort and the load placed upon the destination website.
It would require less JavaScript on the client-side and it's also easier to maintain on the code.

You would secure your accesses per domain.

That's just my two cents, we can discuss it further if you wish.