# Why is request preflighted if I add a standard http header when using cors?

Tags: javascript, http, cors, preflight, custom-headers

I need to add some common extra info (needs to be sent with most of our http requests) to cross domain http requests, the extra data is something like device info or location info. We are using custom http headers for these info currently, but the custom header will make the browser to send an preflight request before the real http request, so we want to remove the preflight request for performance considerations. We considered using cookie firstly, but since the request is cross-domain, we can't set cookie for the domain of our API with javascript. Then I searched for documents, According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS):

> In particular, a request is preflighted if:
>
> It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used
>   to send request data with a Content-Type other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
>   e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using
>   application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.
>
> It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header
>   such as X-PINGOTHER)

So I thought if I use a [standard http header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) which is seldom used: the "From" header, it will not trigger the options request. but after I test this, I found I was wrong, the "From" header still trigger the options request.

So I have two questions:

1. Why does a standard http header trigger the preflight request?
2. How should I send the extra info without trigger the preflight request?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: for the `why` part, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16945321/550618

Answer (score 3):

Read the above portion of the same page on what constitutes a "simple request" that doesn't need to be preflighted:

> Apart from the headers set automatically by the user-agent (e.g. `Connection`, `User-Agent`, etc.), the only headers which are allowed to be set manually are
>
> - `Accept`
> - `Accept-Language`
> - `Content-Language`
> - `Content-Type`

"custom headers" doesn't mean "nonstandard headers", it means any header not automatically set by the browser, other than those four.

Comment: Why the request no longer deemed as "simple" when adding a custom header? In other words, what security implications ensue when adding a header so the CORS mechanism required? Thanks