# Angular:Why my angular app excute every $http request twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http, frontend

I'am sure it execute controllers once, but execute `$http` request twice.So every operation to my DB does twice!

The requests cross domain,and I set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'.

I get OPTIONS request before every normal request,but I guess the OPTIONS request have nothing to do with the TWICE problem.

[image: Request screenshot]

Comment: Without any code it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is preflight CORS requests. Notice that first request is OPTIONS and second one is POST.

This happens when you send request to other domain

Very good explanation: [CORS - What is the motivation behind introducing preflight requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381105/4772988)

Comment: What bothers me is that every request oprates DB twice,will preflight infect DB?How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Depending to your API. But generally you shouldn't touch DB in OPTIONS requests

Comment: I haven't touch DB in my OPTIONS request,actually I don't know how to oprate OPTIONS request.

Comment: Man,thanks for your patience.The backend language is PHP

Comment: It's not my language so just try to debug what is the HTTP context during this first API method execution. Or after your investigation make another question related to your PHP API

Comment: I don't if I have express my situation clearly.My request call API that oprates DB,but I haven't do anytiing with the OPTIONS request,so I think it won't oprate DB.