# Angular2 Post Request sends OPTIONS as header from some reason

Tags: php, angular, post

I cant seem to understand why the request is not sent as a POST request
My code in NG2 is as follows:

`let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers , method:RequestMethod.Post });
    let content = [ { email:email, password: pass } ];
    return this._http.post(this._apiPath, content, options).toPromise()
      .then(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleErrorPromise);`

(I have coded it using the sample from: http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-post-example#example )

within my PHP server i receive the following request:

> [15/May/2017:15:09:32 +0000] "**OPTIONS** /index.php/api/login HTTP/1.1" 404 90 "http://localhost:4200/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"

When i run a simple wget request i receive the following correct request in my PHP Server:

> [15/May/2017:15:02:51 +0000] "**POST** /index.php/api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 96 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
>   web_1            | 2017/05/15 15:02:51 [info] 15#15: *21 client 172.18.0.1 closed keepalive connection

here is the wget command i use:

```
wget --post-data "email=myemail@gmail.com&password=test" http://localhost/index.php/api/login
```

any ideas why does the NG2 doesnt send a POST request?
Thanks.

Comment: you dont have to worry about it. It's just a preflighted request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

You are witnessing whats called a preflighted request. And I would imagine it is happening because of your content-type being set to json.

An OPTIONS request pretty much asks the server if the client is allowed to make a request.

A request will be preflighted... (para-phrasing)

> ...If the Content-Type header has a value other than the following:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

You will need to handle this on your server.

Edit: 
[Here is a pretty good SO answer on CORS and Preflighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests)

Comment: If it was a server issue, how come i can send the proper request from the wget? or are you referring to the NG2 local server?

Comment: @user1322801 read the link I posted. WGET will not be preflighted

Comment: @user1322801 your server will need to respond with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header