# Ionic2 project with Apache PHP REST service on localhost

Tags: apache, rest, angular, ionic2, cors

I have a PHP REST service and a Ionic2 project that 'out of the box' runs on Node.js localhost:8100. The REST service runs on my computer on localhost:80. When I want to do calls from Ionic2 (Angular2) to my server on localhost I get this error in the browser console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/app_dev.php/login. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Wat I understand is that this is a CORS issue (Cross origin resource sharing). As I understand A way to solve this would be to change the build script in ionic to point to a front end distribution location in my Apache project and run the whole project from localhost:80. Another solution is to change the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

- What is the most simple straight forward solution for this problem?

Comment: Please see this[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request] and this[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381105/cors-what-is-the-motivation-behind-introducing-preflight-requests]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the possible duplicates, and there was an potential **[ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35752342/6294072)** to which I want to add some more detail:

Since you are dealing with PHP, the following has worked for me by just adding on top of your php script the following:

```
<?php 

   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); // this!
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type'); // and this!
   //more code here

?>
```

During development, you might very possibly need to enable CORS in your browser, here's an extension for **[CHROME](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)**

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: That extension for CHROME didn't help me.

Comment: Are you still getting same error when setting the header in your PHP script?

Comment: Yes I got the same error, but I needed the  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type') line as well. Now it works perfect! thx!

Comment: For me it has always worked by just adding the first line. Hmm. But awesome that it worked out! :) Have a good day and happy coding! :)