# axios interceptors response undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, interceptor

I'm trying to logout my user once they get a 401. I'm using axios to return data from the api

I was looking around and found the same axios.interceptors.response

```
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
  error => {
    const {status} = error.response;
    if (status === 401 ) {
      store.dispatch('snackBar', snackbarObj)
    } 
   return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)
```

It appears my error.response is undefined. I'm not sure what is wrong? any ideas?

[image: console.dir of the error]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're not getting a response from the request you're doing with Axios since **the browser** received a 401 unauthorized response when doing the preflight `OPTION` request, resulting in a **Network Error** for the request you're trying to do.

This is related to how [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) works and how your backend handles `OPTION` requests. To understand how the backend server should handle preflight requests, it's important to understand [what is the motivation behind introducing preflight requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381105/1218980)

The backend server should not check for authentication on `OPTION` requests, it should validate that the request is being made to an endpoint that accepts cross-domain requests and return a success code if it does.

Then, automatically, the browser will proceed with the initially intended request.

That way, the Axios interceptor will receive the 401 error code if the user is no longer authenticated.

---

*Shameless self-promotion, I've published a simple Axios plugin called [**axios-middleware**](https://github.com/emileber/axios-middleware) which helps abstract the use of Axios interceptors in bigger apps. It offers an example of [middleware that automatically handles unauthenticated requests](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/examples/auth-middleware) by trying to authenticate again before resending the request.*

Comment: How should the Backend be handling it? I’m sending a token in the headers. So on the browser console it says what its in the image above and in the response on the network tab it has “jwt validation failed” – ronoc4 7 hours ago   delete

Comment: @ronoc4 I updated my answer with additional information on preflight requests.

Answer (score 11):

Response object will be undefined also if preflight `OPTION` request ended successfull, but response for next `GET/POST` doesn't contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` http-header.

In my case adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header for nginx 401 response solves problem

Comment: thanks a lot, this is the good solution, i was facing the same problem, and fixed by setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin from express.

Answer (score 4):

For those who still struggling with this, use the following error handling for better control

```
if (error.response) {
  // Request made and server responded
  console.log(error.response.data);
  console.log(error.response.status);
  console.log(error.response.headers);
} else if (error.request) {
   // The request was made but no response was received
   console.log(error.request);
} else {
   // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
   console.log('Error', error.message);
}
return Promise.reject(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not best practice but i solve it this way

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
        response => response,
      error => {
        if (typeof error.response === "undefined") {
          // do somthing
        } 
       return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    )
```