# error.response is undefined if axios request fails

Tags: axios

I cannot access the error (response) status code if an axios request has failed in my Vue.js app. I cannot figure out why the response is undefined in both '.catch' and 'axios.interceptors.response'. I followed this [instruction](https://www.qcode.in/api-error-handling-in-vue-with-axios/) that demonstrates that 'error.response' can be easily accessed with a code like this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => { 
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  },  
  (error) => {
    handleApiFail(error.response);
  });
```

If I add this code to 'main.js' in my app, 'handleApiFail' is called when a request fails, but error.response is undefined in the second lambda and the first lambda is not called. If a request succeeded the 'response' in the first lambda is defined and has the status code.

**EDIT1**: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886315/axios-interceptors-response-undefined) is not an option because my OPTIONS requests do not require authorization. Also there are various [posts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-axios-response-undefined-error) describing the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lack of

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

header in the response caused the browser to block my request.

Adding the header makes axios work fine.

Comment: Is this addressing the question or your immediate problem that led you to this question?

Comment: i am using the same but still the same issue

Answer (score 6):

I have code like this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
    .........
    return Promise.reject();
});
```

Then, I found I miss to return my "error" in promise reject, correct like this:

```
return Promise.reject(error);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an idiosyncrasy of axios. A quick solution to this is to serialize the response:

```
JSON.stringify(error)
```

Please refer to this GitHub issue for more info: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

As someone pointed out there, you can check the error status code in the action and run some other commit depending on it.

Comment: Did you mean adding 'error = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error))' into the second lambda?

Comment: Did you mean Vuex action? How does it relate to axios?

Comment: Check the discussion on GitHub, looks like either axios or vuex (or maybe both) are mangling the error response. The trick (as you pointed out as well) is to JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse the error. Just try that and you should be able to see the actual error response

Comment: I tried 'error = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error))' in the interceptor, but with no success.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much further as I'm not familiar with Vuex, but you might be able to find the solution on the GitHub discussion. They labeled it as a non-issue and closed it, but people are still commenting there.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the operation that may help on some conditions:

```
error = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(error))
```

then try to read the `error.propertyNames` or `error["propertyNames"]`

Thanks

Comment: yes, only in that case I can take status code. s****y lib

Answer (score 0):

You should return `return Promise.reject(error)` in the error function.
If you're developing locally, you'll need to restart the server after the modification.

```js
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```