# Service interceptor not sending response

Tags: javascript, axios

So I'm sending a request, and it is sent sucessfuly, but in `axios` I'm not getting the interceptor back and I don't get why, instead of that I got an error: `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`.

Here is my code for interceptor:

```
listService.interceptors.response.use(
    
    (response) => {
        console.log('Interceptor', response);
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        if(error.response.status == 401){
            console.log("Status of undefined!")
        }
    }
);
```

Here is what I get in console:
[image]

Comment: Can you please use console.log(error) inside the error handler and share the result?

Comment: Might this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886315/axios-interceptors-response-undefined

Comment: @AmirMB okay I realised that problem is with client.isConnected with my mongo database, it's working and it's not working on the same time while posting, it's on the new mongo update, idk what to do.

Comment: I updated the question, what I get in my console after the posting at the first time, in the second time it doesn't work, I have to save my working file. I'm working in vue.js