# Why axios.interceptors.response.use was not contain a error.status

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to get a refersh token when api response is 401. But when  I log the error.status
it undefiend or not exist!!

Bellow is my code :

```
Axios.interceptors.response.use((res) => res,
    async (error) => {
      console.log(error);
})
```

What is aproblem? How Can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [axios interceptors response undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886315/axios-interceptors-response-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Try to grab the status from `error.response.status`.

Comment: unfortunately error.response is undefiend

Comment: what is inside the `error` object?