# Why does a cross-origin simple POST request not trigger a preflight check?

Tags: javascript, rest, http, cors, same-origin-policy

Why does a cross-origin simple POST request not trigger a preflight check? [From the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

```
A request that doesn’t trigger a CORS preflight—a so-called “simple request”...

The only allowed methods are:
    - GET
    - HEAD
    - POST

...

The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
    - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    - multipart/form-data
    - text/plain
```

However if a user visits evilsite.com, and they are tricked into filling out a form that simply has a form action="http://elsewhere.com", and the servers on elsewhere.com are expecting valid post requests with multipart/form-data (or any of the other 2 really) wouldn't that NOT protect the servers on elsewhere.com? Shouldn't these in fact be subject to the CORS preflight checks? What am I missing here

Comment: does elsewhere.com allow CORS? if not, nothing evilsite.com can do about it ... CORS is *controlled by the server not the client*

Comment: Servers that were developed before CORS was ever around would have no concept of "allowing cors" they would be operating under the assumption that _all_ posts requests to it would be subject to same-origin policy.

Comment: correct, so no cross origin resource sharing would NOT be allowed, because the old servers wont, because they know nothing of CORS headers, therefore don't send them, therefore no problem - you need to understand CORS better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...the servers on `elsewhere.com` are expecting valid post requests with `multipart/form-data` (or any of the other 2 really) wouldn't that NOT protect the servers on `elsewhere.com`?

That's right, it wouldn't, and it would be a major security failure on the part of `elsewhere.com` to "expect valid post requests". That attack—[Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)—exists with or without CORS, and it is up to the server to protect against it.

CORS was introduced to make cross-origin requests possible without introducing any *new* security problems. It doesn't address this existing security problem because doing so would have a cost (the preflight requests aren't free) but no benefit (since servers would still have to protect themselves from browsers that aren't using CORS).

I've written about this in more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687744/2395796).