# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' CORS error only in method to download .PDF file using .NET and Angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, cors

I have an application with .NET 7 and Angular 16 and i make a lot of requests from client to server and all works fine. My problem happens in a specific method that i am using to download a PDF file. Furthermore, this error only happens in production server. The error say (in the chrome console):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.17.40.93:5000/Report/GenerateEggResultsReport' from origin 'http://10.17.40.93:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Example of request **that work**:ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

- Angular side:

```
getUserResults(startDate: string): Observable<ResponseBase> {
  const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('startDate', startDate);

  return this.http.get<ResponseBase>(environment.apiUrl + 'Report/getUserResults',
    {
      params,
      headers: { 'LangInfo': this.baseService.currentLanguage.enumValue }
    });
}
```

- .NET side

```
[HttpGet("GetUserResults")]
public JsonResult GetUserResults(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, bool isOptoClass, EShiftType? shiftType)
{
    try
    {
        var eggResults = _machineReportAppService.GetUserResults(startDate, endDate, isOptoClass, shiftType);

        return ResponseBase.StatusReturn(EReturnStatus.Success, eggResults);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var returnStatus = ex.Message == Translator.Translate("NoMachineOperationFound") ? EReturnStatus.CleanLoadedData : EReturnStatus.Error;

        var returnMessage = !ex.Message.IsNullOrEmpty() ? ex.Message : Translator.Translate("ErrorGettingEggResults");

        return ResponseBase.StatusReturn(returnStatus, returnMessage);
    }
}
```

Example of request **that don't work**:

- Angular side:

```
generateReportFile(eggResultsReportFileRequest: EggResultsReportFileRequest): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
  return this.http.post<Blob>(environment.apiUrl + 'Report/GenerateEggResultsReportFile', eggResultsReportFileRequest, {
    observe: 'response',
    responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'LangInfo': this.baseService.currentLanguage.enumValue
    }
  });
}
```

- .NET side:

```
[HttpPost("GenerateEggResultsReportFile")]
public IActionResult GenerateEggResultsReportFile(EggResultsReportFileRequest eggResultsReportFileRequest)
{
    try
    {
        CreateLog(eggResultsReportFileRequest);

        var eggResultsReport = _machineReportAppService.GenerateEggResultsReportFile(eggResultsReportFileRequest);

        return File(eggResultsReport.ReportContent, eggResultsReport.ReportExtension);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(Translator.Translate("ErrorGeneratingReport"));
    }
}
```

Comment: two quick ideas: (1) sometimes when the preflight request fails for any reason, the surfacing error may still be reported as CORS error although it is something else. debug the server side, look for exceptions. (2) the allow-origin header is a *response* header, not a request header.

Comment: thanks, your answer makes me realize that the problem is in server side. I hope the things will be easier from now

Answer (score 2):

The main difference I see between your examples is that one is a GET request and another is a POST request.
CORS policies are different for GET and POST requests.

Perhaps this answer can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64714974/11905918